# Set svn:ignore property on anything in a particular folder (but not the folder itself)

Tags: svn, svnignore

I have this folder

```
public/assets/dvd_files/dvds/
```

and i want to svn ignore anything that might appear in it.  I thought that this would work:

```
 svn propset svn:ignore * public/assets/dvd_files/dvds/
```

but i get this error message back:

```
svn: Cannot set 'svn:ignore' on a file ('Capfile')
```

Can anyone set me straight as to what i'm doing wrong here?
cheers, max

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need quotes around the * to stop your shell from expanding it into a list of all the files in the current folder.

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*" public/assets/dvd_files/dvds/
```

With the * expanded, you're effectively running

```
svn propset svn:ignore file1 file2 file3 file4 public/assets/dvd_files/dvds/
```

which is interpreted as setting the value of svn:ignore to "file1" on the file file2

Comment: "*" does not expand as you describe.   Running your second command won't work.

Comment: @Alex: The second command isn't supposed to work, it's illustrating what Max's original command really runs after expansion and why that doesn't work. The first command is the correct one, preventing the unwanted expansion, and works just fine.

Comment: Ahhh... From the text of your answer, I thought you were describing the "*" in your first code line.   It wasn't clear to me.  Thanks for the clarification.